# Как избежать TLE?

Tags: c++

> Найдите количество правильных несократимых дробей, не превосходящих X, знаменатель которых не превосходит N.
>   Ограничения: 2 <= N <= 100000. X - макс. 4 знака после запятой.

В моей книге описано такое решение: строить ряд Фарея до тех пор, пока очередная дробь не будет больше чем X. Но при предельных значениях N, ответ может быть больше 10^9 (в последнем тесте ответ 3 * 10^9), а это значит, что с таким решением я словлю TLE. Написав реализацию, получил TLE.

Вот код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long double gcd(long double af, long double bf) {
    long a = af, b = bf;
    if (a < b) {
        swap(a, b);
    }

    while (b) {
        (a) %= b;
        swap(a, b);
    }

    return a;
}

long double lcm(long double a, long double b) 
{
    return a / gcd(a, b) * b;
}

long power[] = { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000};

class fraction
{
    public:

        long double nominator;
        long double denominator;

        fraction(long nom, long denom): nominator(nom), denominator(denom)
        {}

        fraction(long double k)
        {
            k *= 10000;
            nominator = k / gcd(k, 10000);
            denominator = 10000 / gcd(k, 10000);
        }

        bool operator<=(fraction f)
        {
            long LCM = lcm(denominator, f.denominator);
            return (nominator * LCM / denominator <= f.nominator * LCM / f.denominator)? true : false;
        }

        void display()
        {
            cout << nominator << "/" << denominator << endl;
        }

};

int main()
{
    long double k;
    long N;
    long long count = 1;
    cin >> k;
    fraction K(k);
    cin >> N;
    fraction second(1, N-1);
    fraction first(1, N);
    while(second <= K)
    {
        count++;
        long long n = N, a = first.nominator, b = first.denominator, c = second.nominator, d = second.denominator;
        fraction temp(((n + b) / d)*c-a, ((n+b) / d)*d-b);
        first = second;
        second = temp;
    }
    cout << count;

}
```

Автор книги ошибся или моя реализация косячная?

Comment: *"Аааа!!!! Только не это, шеф! Только не это!"* (с)  Не используйте для сугубо целочисленных вычислений числа с плавающей точкой! Есть же `long long` - используйте его. Но `gcd` для плавающей точки - бред!

Comment: Так я в gcd доп. переменные ввёл. Так листинг конечно неприятный, но всё работает.

Comment: я бы вообще перебирал знаменатель от 1 до N (100к вариантов) и просто вычислял количество чисел от 1 до N*X которые взаимнопросты с N. Ну это можно легко сделать через разложение N на множители дальше известная формула.

Comment: тоже так хотел. асимптотика получается (sqrt(N))^3. Но перед тем как писать, решил почитать что автор по этому поводу пишет. и вот..

Comment: @NikolayBelov 1 - решето эрастосфена. И поиск делителей становится сильно быстрее. 2 - а куб то откуда?)

Comment: @pavel Может я туплю, но решето Эратосфена ищет простые делители числа, а нам нужно все взаимно простые числа.. По поводу куба просчитался, мы смотрим N знаменателей, для каждого sqrt(NK) и в итоге N * sqrt(NK).

Comment: @NikolayBelov https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0 как из простых получить все. Я думал это школьная программа если честно)